# Understanding Recursion in Python Stack

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to get my head around recursion and when I write a small piece of code I have no idea how it reached the specific output for example.

```
x = 0
def recursion():
    global x
    x += 1
    print(x)
    while x < 5:
        recursion()
        recursion()
        print("example")
    print("test")
recursion()
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
test
6
test
example
test
7
test
example
test
8
test
example
test
9
test
example
test
```

I would be super grateful if someone could explain it step by step.

Comment: You should use a debugger to see whats happening, step by step. I would reccommend PyCharm's breakpoints. You could even use IDLE's debugger (Which is helpfull showing the source) or pdb.

Comment: For a program like this, an interactive visualizer like [Python Tutor's](http://www.pythontutor.com/) is amazingly helpful. There's only 73 instructions in the whole program, but it's not immediately obvious what the sequence is, so stepping forward and backward through those 73 (and seeing what the stack frame looks like every time `x` gets tested or changed) is exactly what you need to understand this code.

Comment: For code that runs for millions of steps and hundreds of values, you don't want to look at all of them, so then you _will_ need a full-featured debugger, which lets you run until the next breakpoint, see only the stuff you care about, etc.There's a bit more of a learning curve, but on this other hand, this is a perfect time to learn: First Python Tutor this until you understand it, then figure out how to get the same information out of `pdb` or a GUI wrapper around it. (It's much easier to learn now, with a small program that you fully understand…)

Comment: @adam-dunn, is your question answered ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what happens, step by step. At first call :

```
def recursion():
      global x
      x += 1
      print(x)  # x ==1
      while x < 5:
        recursion() # on hold, executing recursion

def recursion():
      global x
      x += 1
      print(x)  # x ==2
      while x < 5:
        recursion() # on hold, executing recursion
.
.
.
.

def recursion():
      global x
      x += 1  
      print(x) # x == 5, skipping while loop
      while x < 5:
        recursion()
      print('test') # printing test
```

Now resuming all the calls that were on hold:

```
def recursion():
      global x
      x += 1
      print(x)
      while x < 5:
        recursion() # Called when x == 1
        recursion() # Resuming, this will put x to 6 and print it, won't enter the loop, so prints test directly
        print('example') # print example


def recursion():
      global x
      x += 1
      print(x)
      while x < 5:
        recursion() # Called when x == 2
        recursion() # Resuming, this will put x to 7 and print it, won't enter the loop, so prints test directly
        print('example') # print example
```

until the call where x==4

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @abarnert's recommendation of using an *interactive visualizer*.  However, this code snippet is sufficiently short that we can fully instrument it:

```
indent = 0

print('\t' * indent, "x = 0"); x = 0

def recursion(indent):
    global x; indent += 1

    print('\t' * indent, "x += 1"); x += 1
    print('\t' * indent, 'print(x)'); print(x)

    while x < 5:
        print('\t' * indent, "while x < 5:")
        print('\t', '\t' * indent, "recursion()"); recursion(indent + 1)
        print('\t', '\t' * indent, "recursion()"); recursion(indent + 1)

        print('\t', '\t' * indent, 'print("example")'); print("example")

    print('\t' * indent, 'print("test")'); print("test")

print('\t' * indent, "recursion()"); recursion(indent)
```

Running it, we get your results on the left and what the program is doing at each step is indented:

```
> python3 test.py
 x = 0
 recursion()
     x += 1
     print(x)
1
     while x < 5:
         recursion()
             x += 1
             print(x)
2
             while x < 5:
                 recursion()
                     x += 1
                     print(x)
3
                     while x < 5:
                         recursion()
                             x += 1
                             print(x)
4
                             while x < 5:
                                 recursion()
                                     x += 1
                                     print(x)
5
                                     print("test")
test
                                 recursion()
                                     x += 1
                                     print(x)
6
                                     print("test")
test
                                 print("example")
example
                             print("test")
test
                         recursion()
                             x += 1
                             print(x)
7
                             print("test")
test
                         print("example")
example
                     print("test")
test
                 recursion()
                     x += 1
                     print(x)
8
                     print("test")
test
                 print("example")
example
             print("test")
test
         recursion()
             x += 1
             print(x)
9
             print("test")
test
         print("example")
example
     print("test")
test
>
```

Clearly, only useful for small examples.  (But worth doing at least once in the process of learning recursion!) This is essentially what an *interactive visualizer* will do for you, saving you much time and trouble.